# On a linux system, how can I record variable length segments in Pyaudio until I stop talking in a noisy environment using streams?

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio, microphone, noise

I'm trying to create a virtual agent.  I've used code that records variable length commands before -- but in a quieter environment.  Now it doesn't get beyond the while loop as the data variable is never empty.

```
def listen():
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "temp.wav"
CHUNK = 1024
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1,rate=16000, input=Trueframes_per_buffer=1024)
frames = []
try:
    while True:
        data = stream.read(4000)
        frames.append(data)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

len(data) is always 4000; so this idea is just wrongheaded.  Sorry. How do I close this question?